# extract all occurrences of same field from request body splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a same field multiple times in one request body and need to find the value for each occurrence. like subTypeCodeId filed. result should have subTypeCodeId = 2
subTypeCodeId = 3

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "emailId": "@stny.com",
      "item": {
        "subTypeCodeId": "2"
      }
    },
    {
      "emailId": "@comcast.com",
      "item": {
        "subTypeCodeId": "3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

splunk query: index="gcp_prod_ecomm_cx_wallet" "1570081534220" "*API_NAME:wallet.addItemsToWalletBulk*" |rex "subTypeCodeId\x5C\":\x5C\"(?.*)\""

Answer (score 0):

Use the `max_match` option of `rex`.  It will make subTypeCodeId a multi-value field containing all values.

```
index="gcp_prod_ecomm_cx_wallet" "1570081534220" "API_NAME:wallet.addItemsToWalletBulk" 
| rex max_match=0 "subTypeCodeId\x5C\":\x5C\"(?<subTypeCodeId>.*)\""
```

You also might want to look into the `spath` command, which can parse json data.